# Spring Boot OAuth2 when implicit JWT is created?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-lemon

How can I get details from the OAuth2 SSO `Principal` into my JWT? (instance of `OAuth2Authentication` `getDetails` as `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails` `getDecodedDetails` returns `null`)

I have...

- Angular 6 client w/ implicit login as `acme` client (using `angular-oauth2-oidc`)
- Spring Boot OAuth2 Authorization Server with JWT `TokenService` configuration w/ 3rd party SSO to GitHub
- Auth server is configured with `acme` as `implicit` and GitHub client for SSO
- Auth server exposes a `/login/github`
- Auth server exposes a `/me` (protected by ResourceServer config)

When I login...

1. Angular app redirects to Auth service login
2. Auth service redirects to GitHub
3. [User Authenticates]
4. GitHub redirects to Auth Service
5. Auth Service initiates a session and issues a token
6. Auth Service redirects to Angular
7. The browser token is a proper JWT

Now, when I communicate with Auth Service `/me`:

- Directly, I get a `Principal` that contains ALL of the details from GitHub (yay)
- Indirectly from the Angular application passing the token via `Authorization: Bearer ...` header, I get a `Principal` that contains bare minimum OAuth client info for `acme` client (ugh)

I've tried a custom `TokenEnhancer`, but the `OAuth2Authentication` instance is already the bare minimum with no details. And, when the call is initiated from Angular, it doesn't have the same session cookie as when I call it directly (I don't want to share session - I want to put the details in the JWT).

**[Update #1]**

I tried a custom `JwtAccessTokenConverter` and used it in both of the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and `@EnableResourceServer` (secures the `/me` endpoint) configuration classes. However it didn't work. I still get null details from `OAuth2Authentication`.

```
final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
converter.setAccessTokenConverter(new CustomTokenConverter());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) does this is replacing the OAuth2 and OpenID connect user services (see [spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-advanced-oauth2-user-service)). See `LemonOAuth2UserService` and `LemonOidcUserService` for details. For statelessness, it passes the client a shortlived JWT token as a param to targetUrl, as you can see in its `OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler` class. It uses some cookies mechanism for doing all this statelessly, which can be further understood by looking at its `HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository` and how it's configured.

Here is an article explaining this in more details: https://www.naturalprogrammer.com/blog/1681261/spring-security-5-oauth2-login-signup-stateless-restful-web-services .